# How can I disable the vertical scroll bar on just the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, scroll-bars

Look at this tiny scroll bar (circled in red):

> [image: screenshot]

I think I could use the elisp function `set-window-scroll-bars`, but I don't know how to specify the minibuffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fledermaus` solved the puzzle:

Add this to `init.el`:

```
(set-window-scroll-bars (minibuffer-window) nil nil)
```

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, consider maybe `0 'none` for the last two arguments?

Comment: Works on GNU/Linux (Fedora with Gnome), too.